# Using application.caller to change other cells

Tags: vba, excel

If I for example have this in the code of a function:

```
If TypeOf Application.Caller Is Range Then
    Rng = Application.Caller
    With Rng
        With .Offset(0, -4)
            .Value = 0
        End With
        With .Offset(0, -6)
            .Value = 0
        End With
    End With
End If
```

It returns error.

How would I go about changing the value of other cells using Application.Caller.Offset when calling a function?

Comment: You want to modify other cells in a certain worksheet ?

Comment: No. I want to modifycells that are in the same sheet as the function called. I want to do it based on .Offset. So if I call this function in B8 then cell B4 and B2 would have value 0.

Comment: A function normally returns a value. How are you calling it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change other cells in a function - Excel won't let you. This feature is by design: a function may only change the cell in which it is entered

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, you want to use `Offset` with `Row` parameter, not column.

If you send `Range("B8")` to your current code, using `With .Offset(0, -4)` will result in an error !  Since you have 2 (for column "B") and you use `Offset` of `-4` >> `2 - 4 = -2`

> = Run-Time Error

change:

```
With .Offset(0, -4)
```

To:

```
With .Offset(-4, 0)
```

And also:

```
With .Offset(0, -6)
```

To:

```
With .Offset(-6, 0)
```

---

You could use the code below to get the result you want:

```
Sub ChangeOffsetCells(Rng As Range)

With Rng
    With .Offset(-4, 0)
        .Value = 0
    End With
    With .Offset(-6, 0)
        .Value = 0
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

and use the little `Test` sub below to test it:

```
Sub Test()

ChangeOffsetCells Range("B8")

End Sub
```